# Daemon eats too much CPU when being idle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, daemon, ruby-daemons

I am using [blue-daemons](https://github.com/bluepill-rb/daemons) fork of [daemons](https://github.com/ghazel/daemons) gem (since the second one looks totally abandoned) along with [daemons-rails](https://github.com/mirasrael/daemons-rails) gem, which wraps daemons for rails.

The problem is that my daemon eats too much CPU when it's idle (10-20 times higher then it's actually performing the job).

By being idle, I mean that I have special flag - `Status.active?`. If `Status.active?` is `true`, then I perform the job, if it's `false`, then I just sleep 10 secs and iterate next step in the `while($running) do` block and check status again and again.

I don't want to hard stop job because there is really sensitive data and I don't want the process to break it. Is there any good way to handle that high CPU usaget? I tried Sidekiq, but it looks like it's primary aim is to run jobs on demand or on schedule, but I need the daemon to run on non-stop basis.

```
$running = true
Signal.trap("TERM") do 
  $running = false
end

while($running) do
  while Status.active? do
       ..... DO LOTS OF WORK ..... 
  else
     sleep 10
  end
end
```

Comment: I just ran [this](http://lpaste.net/110842) and I am getting 0% CPU. Are you sure you aren't doing anything else? Also, `while predicate do ... else ... end` isn't valid.

Comment: Looks like it was my bad, thank you. Fixing `while` syntax did it for me

Comment: How were you even able to run it with bad syntax? It should have returned immediately stating there was an issue.

Comment: There was an error but daemon were rerunning code each time and returning error in the loop. That's why it was eating so much CPU